# How use AdsCopyTableStructure to create ttAdsCDX table

Tags: advantage-database-server

Using Advantage Server 9x, I am trying to create a copy of a DBF/CDX table structure using the following code:

```
table1.AdsCopyTableStructure(d.AdsConnectionTemp.connectPath+'table.dbf');
```

The table that is created is of the type ttAdsADT, even though the original table is ttAdsCDX.

I tried using AdsConvertTable on the resulting table, but it pops an exception complaining that the operation cannot be done on free tables.

Any way to do this?

Comment: To be honest, I have not had any issues with this function.  You are certain that the base table is ttAdsCDX?  Also, as Doug mentioned below you should have no problem using AdsConvertTable.  I am not sure if it is possible here, but perhaps more of a sample including the table, etc. can give more information.

Comment: Hi Edgar, which version of ADS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this function to work, but came up with a work around by using the following code:

```
 t:=TAdsTable.create(nil);
 try
      t.AdsTableOptions.AdsFilterOptions:=RESPECT_WHEN_COUNTING;
      t.open;
      t.AdsSetAOF('keyval=-1'); // gives an empty result
      t.AdsCopyTable('c:\somewhere\emlt.dat');
      t.close;
 finally
      freeAndNil(t);
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.
If you don't mind having a single record you can always do

Select top 1 * into mynewtable.dbf from oldtable

which is quick

A second option would be to do your first method, saving it to an adt file (which is the default) then open THAT table and use ADSConvertTable function to create the DBF.

ADTTable.ADSTableConvert('dbftable.dbf',ttADSCDX);

Answer (score 0):

```
QDSPRINTLIG.AdsConvertTable(gcTmpDir + gcTempFile + '.dbf',ttADSCDX);
```

It is still working after 13 years :))

Comment: what 13 years are you referring to?